# How to correctly pass an object to a custom directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a very "simple" goal: I have a kind of form creator, and this directive is expected to "render" the content of the form.

For that, I created a custom directive which I am planing to pass the object and create a logic for rendering trough templates. However, I am failing to pass the object to the custom directive

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">

    <p>Components starts</p>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <!-- <p>{{item}}</p> -->
        <my-component obj="item" ></my-component>
    </div>
    <p>Components ends</p>

</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope) {

    $scope.items = [
        { type: 'TextArea', data: 'Somedata1', mandatory: true },
        { type: 'List', data: 'Somedata2', mandatory: false },
        { type: 'Select', data: 'Somedata3', mandatory: true }];

})
.directive('myComponent', function() {
    return {  
        restric: 'E',
        scope: { obj: '=obj' },
        template: '<div> This is the template for {{obj.type}} </div>'
    };
});
```

I have made and changed the code many times with different examples I got on the web, but after 2 days I was not able to make it work (yes, it is shameful)

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielBarcia/3s682zve/5/)

I know the issue is when passing to the directive, because if I remove the comment tag from the ng-repeat, the data is show correctly, but if I try to use the directive it does not work.

Please, can anyone help me and explain me why this is not working and what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for providing the jsfiddle.  I'm not sure I would have spotted the problem without it.

Turns out you were misspelling `restrict` (you left off the 't' at the end), and you needed to leave out the reference to `scope` in the view.

Check out your updated (and working) [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8whhyj3p/).

Comment: Thank you very much. Although I consider myself an amateur, this took me off 2 days before posting the question. I checked and updated the fiddle and is working fine. Appreciate the explanation as well